# how to copy column data into new column in same table

Tags: sql, rdbms

```
update employee set JoiningDate=Cast(DateofJoining as date);
```

I am copy joiningDate column data into Dateofjoining column...i want copy all rows data from joiningdate column into Dateofjoining column
joiningdate is varcharchar and Date of joining is date

Error is:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Seems like there are non-valid date values in your column.

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have rows which contain string format that cannot be used as DATE format. first remove those entries then try again

Comment: alter table employee alter column DateofJoining date;

Comment: alter table employee alter column DateofJoining date;     iam trying in alter table but no use,error is::Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: yes you are asking the thing again. did you tried what i said?

Answer (score 0):

I'm waiting for your DBMS but:

You can do this flow:

- Add a new column DateofJoining2 with datetime
- Write an UPDATE script (so you can manage your old data into new column)
- Drop the old column (if your step 2 it's OK)
- Rename the column with the old name DateofJoining

If you write your DBMS, I can write the exact DDL and DML scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Your_table] ADD New_Column Date UPDATE your_table SET  New_Column = CAST(Old_Column as Date) ALTER TABLE Your_table DROP COLUMN Old_Column
```

Comment: how to copy column1 value into new column2 in one table

Comment: update old column value to new column.I mentioned in above query

Comment: Update employee set JoiningDate=cast(DateofJoining as date)

Comment: what is your output for above query

Comment: error is::Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.